# Why does php abort on client disconnecting when printing data but not otherwise?

Tags: javascript, php, loops, connection, server-sent-events

I'm employing SSE using php and javascript.

I have a loop (with a lifespan of 15 seconds for dev purposes) that runs through and adds a "start conenction", "still here" (after sleeping for 1 second), and an "end connection" to the database for debugging purposes.

I've found that when the php script runs without "print"ing/"echo"ing/"var_dump()"ing any information, the script (read "loop") runs to completion regardless of if the client has terminated connection or not.

However, when I print/echo/var_dump anything - the script terminates as soon as the user terminates.

Why does this difference exist?

Comment: By default the script should be aborted when the client disconnects. If you have the `ignore_user_abort` option set in `php.ini`, it disables this. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php.

Comment: `ignore_user_abort` is not set in my `php.ini`, but when you have a loop running, the loop does not end even after user disconnection. (Unless you print/echo/dump an output).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the script should be aborted when the client disconnects. There are a few ways this could be overridden:

- Set the `ignore_user_abort` option in `php.ini`.
- Set the `php_value ignore_user_abort` option in `httpd.conf`.
- Call `ignore_user_abort()` in the PHP script.
- Register a shutdown function with `register_shutdown_function()` in the PHP script.

Comment: None of these things were done in my script/server setup - yet upon calling a php file using SSE from javascript if the php file has a loop, and it does not output anything using `print` `echo` etc.. It keeps running after user disconnects.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with SSE. Maybe that doesn't manage the connection from the client the same way a normal download of a web page does, so the disconnection isn't detected similarly.

Comment: Also, do you have to program the PHP script differently if it's doing SSE?

Comment: That may be it. I am thinking that the same situation will result with an AJAX call to the script and will have to test it when I get some time. I do not have to program the PHP script any differently, other than making sure the script stays alive for a certain period of time with a loop. This is to ensure that the client browser does not keep making "subscription" requests as part of its default behavior for SSE.